# Flutter: How to rebuild using Riverpod within showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final provider = counterNotifierProviders(Counter.initialize());
    final counter = ref.watch(provider);
  
  return Scaffold(
    body: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text(counter.count),
                TextButton(child: 'Add' onPressed: () => ref.read(provider.notifier).add()),
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`Text(counter.count)` is not updated. But, I know `counter.count` was updating from log.

How I can resolve that problem?

Comment: Is this inside a Stateful widget?

Comment: @Dani3le_ No. I use ConsumerWidget instead of that.

Comment: Hi @hbk, please share your code for the `StateNotifier` class that you wrote.

Comment: @Josteve Thank your comments. I resolved the problem using StatefulBuilder. But, I have trouble with the parent widget is not rebuild after closed BottomSheet.  Should I use StatefulBuilder for this problem too? Do you know a better way to resolve it?

Comment: @zbk, How did you resolve it by using StatefulBuilder together with Riverpod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using Consumer to use its ref and rebuild the widget for you:

```
Consumer(
        builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
     return Scaffold(...);
});
```

Comment: I used consumer inside bottom sheet. its not working, value is updating from log but not reflecting in bottom sheet. Basically i want to show progressBar in bottomsheet. value is coming from sockets and i am reading values in statenotifier